# Minimizing mean absolute percentage error by a constant.

Tags: calculus, optimization, error-function

The task is to minimize the mean absolute percentage error (MAPE) by constant C.
$$MAPE = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=0}^N{|\frac{y_i - C}{y_i}}|$$
Given values $y_0, .., y_N$. Find the constant C at which the error function (MAPE) shows the minimum value.

Is it possible to solve this problem?